# En / dans ces vertes années

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

*Plus tard, je serai un enfant* d'Éric-Emmanuel Schmitt :

> Catherine me troubla lorsqu'elle m'annonça son projet éditorial :
> interroger des artistes sur leur enfance qui, selon elle, constitue le
> véritable atelier de leur création. **En** ces vertes années, dans leurs
> malheurs ou leurs bonheurs, dans la plénitude ou le manque, ils ont
> puisé l'envie, l'énergie, le besoin de peindre, de composer, d'écrire.

Est-il aussi possible d'écrire ***Dans** ces vertes années* ?

Comment: C'est logiquement équivalent, la nuance est dans l'évocation du temps : « ***En [ce temps-là, celui de]** ces vertes années* », les années de l'action sont incluses dans un temps plus long, plus générique que celui des années de l'enfance, et c'est le contraire ensuite, l'action/l'enfance concernée se passe « ***Dans (ou durant)** ces vertes années*. »

Comment: Au cours de ces vertes années...

Comment: @Lambie — Au cours renvoie à *en* : ‘[à] le cours’ (du temps) voit passer “ces vertes années”, il était là avant et continue après.

Comment: @Personne, Il me semble que le paragraphe décrit des trucs qui ont **duré** pour une période de temps. Donc, pour moi, "au cours de" c'est une autre façon de dire la période entendue comme les vertes années.

Comment: @Lambie … choix tout à fait personnel pour évoquer une époque : *dans* rattacherait plutôt à une période, par exemple les années soixante *dans/durant* laquelle plusieurs artistes ont émergé, *en* peut se passer n'importe quand, voire depuis des millénaires (dans la question il s'agit seulement d'interroger des artistes vivants de tout âge), chaque artiste a vu son art verdir puis murir *en son temps* (celui de l'arrivée de la créativité dans le quotidien d'une personne).

Comment: @Personne Merci pour votre réponse.

Comment: @Personne le nom de jlliagre s'écrit sans "i" entre "j" et "l", j + l + l +i +a + g+ r + e. Moi aussi je pensais au début qu'après "j" il y a un "i". :)

Comment: — Bigre ! Ma vue baisse vraiment depuis longtemps  … et pourtant je l'ai applaudi sans m'en rendre compte lorsqu'il a passé la barre des 100k  :-)  — Je replace mon commentaire ici : « Bien que différente dans ses arguments, la réponse de @jlliagre rapproche *dans* d'une époque/période et *en* [d'un moment de vie] d'un artiste. »

Comment: @Personne Non, je crois que l'on lit trop rapidement, le mot en entier. Et puis, c'est réellement mélangeant, son nom :) "mélangeant" Qc = "qui prête à confusion".

Comment: @Oreste Oui, ce sont beaucoup les anglophones qui lisent "Jill" au début de mon pseudo mélangeant ;-) Je ne suis cependant pas près d'en changer. J'ai celui là depuis bien trente-cinq ans, la préhistoire d'Internet...

Answer (score 2):

Je ne pense pas que la préposition ***en*** introduise ici une proposition circonstancielle de temps.

***En*** introduit plutôt, métaphoriquement, une proposition circonstancielle de lieu, comme **dans** qui aurait donc pu être utilisé.

Éric-Emmanuel Schmitt indique ***où*** sont puisés *l'envie, l'énergie, le besoin de peindre, de composer, d'écrire*. Les artistes les puisent ***dans*** *leur enfance, dans leurs malheurs, bonheurs, plénitude, manque*. L'action de puiser ne s'est donc pas déroulée lors de leur enfance mais à l'âge adulte. Le verbe ***puiser*** s'utilise habituellement avec la préposition ***dans***, mais ***en*** se rencontre parfois, et c'est même la seule préposition rencontrée dans quelques expressions comme ***puiser en soi***, qui est justement très proche du sens global de la phrase de la question.

Comment: Merci. C'est possible. Mais pourquoi alors ne pas employer "en" par la suite _**en** leurs malheurs ou leurs bonheurs, **en** la plénitude ou le manque_ ? Ce serait plus logique... du point de vue de la symétrie.

Comment: Bonne remarque sur la symétrie. Je dirais que le premier ***en*** est littéraire, mais ***en** leur bonheur...* aurait été trop affecté.  *Je veux qu’il puise **en** moi, **dans** ma pureté, l’éclat dont il doit se revêtir pour être unique.* Joë Bousquet, *Lettres à Poisson d'Or*, 1968; *Alors que je puise **en** moi **dans** des réserves d'énergies insoupçonnées, un visage fait irruption dans mon esprit, décuplant ma colère*, Jordan Breton, *Sang Rancune*, 2020.

Comment: Ce n'est quand même qu'une interprétation personnelle. Peut-être que Catherine dit vraiment que l'atelier en question a débuté dès l'enfance des artistes.

Comment: _Peut-être que Catherine dit vraiment que l'atelier en question a débuté dès l'enfance des artistes._ --- Peut-être. Elle seule le sait. :) Ou il se peut qu'elle ait oublié ce qu'elle voulait dire exactement.

Comment: C'est possible. Somme toute, il n'y a pas de différence fondamentale entre les deux : "Puiser quelque chose durant son enfance, dans les expériences qu'on y vit" et "Puiser quelque chose dans son enfance, dans les expériences qu'on y a vécu".

Answer (score 1):

« Dans » n'est pas aussi littéraire mais peut aussi être utilisé.

([réf. 2018](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Nouvelles_valeurs_dans_l_Angleterre_d_au/Xy5KDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22dans+ces+ann%C3%A9es%22&pg=PA72&printsec=frontcover)) On montrera qu'à travers ce débat sur la sexualité et la médecine, la presse opère une série de clivages qui contribuent à saper les bases traditionnelles de la société anglaise dans ces années.

([réf. 2019](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_Indig%C3%A9nat_Gen%C3%A8ses_dans_l_empire_fran/UB-QDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22dans+ces+ann%C3%A9es%22&pg=PA153&printsec=frontcover)) Maillons essentiels de la chaîne du commandement colonial, ils sont aussi tenus dans ces années 1880 de jouer les intermédiaires entre l'ensemble des communautés en présence dans le pays, colons, engagistes, engagés, Kanak, condamnés et ...

([réf. 2017](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_%C3%89poque_de_la_Renaissance_1400_1600/7rU_DwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22dans+ces+ann%C3%A9es%22&pg=PA308&printsec=frontcover)) De nombreux textes mis en musique dans ces années évoquent d'ailleurs explicitement la question de « dire ou ne pas dire » le secret (sexuel) qui se cache derrière les codes de la séduction courtoise, de parler ouvertement ou non de ...

([réf. 2021](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_Bouquin_de_la_bande_dessin%C3%A9e/hAkCEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22dans+ces+ann%C3%A9es%22&pg=PT691&printsec=frontcover)) Mais le dessinateur qui, en France, dans ces années-là, livre l'œuvre la plus ouvertement psychédélique est sans aucun doute Guy Peellaert. L'adjectif *psychédélique* prend tout son sens avec She and the Green Hair (publié dans Hara-Kiri ...

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en)) **2.** [En introduit un compl. circonst. de temps]
> **a)** [Sans idée de direction]
> **Littér. ou dans des loc. figées.** En + déterminatif
> **En + adj. dém.**
> ♦ Le monde était riche, en ce temps-là. (Beauvoir, Mandarins,1954, p. 494)
> ♦ En ces minutes qui dépassent chacune de nos pauvres vies.  (De Gaulle, Mémoires de guerre,1956, p. 308)